# What does Holding Home Button on Power Off Screen do?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

When you hold the home button on the power off screen of an iDevice on the lockscreen or Springboard, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you continue to hold, you get Siri [iPhone 4S & up]; even from the power-down screen…

…otherwise, you trigger fingerprint security, which requires you to touch but not press the home button from the lock screen to unlock the device [iPhone 5S & up].